# How to get OpenId Connect Configuration from ./well-known/openid-connect URL in OWIN?

Tags: c#, asp.net, owin, keycloak, openid-connect

I am migrating legacy ASP.Net application to support OpenId Connect Authentication with Keycloak Identity Provider. For this i have used OWIN OpenId Middleware and it works, but now I require to implement session management.

Keycloak offer its by using `check_session_iframe` endpoint, its url resides on OpenId Configuration in uri: `http://192.168.99.100:8180/auth/realms/[realm_name]/.well-known/openid-configuration`

I know that OWIN OpenId Middleware use `OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions` which contains property `Configuration` of type `OpenIdConnectConfiguration` where an equivalent of .well-known/openid-configuration file is parsed during Authentication flow.

It is possible to retrieve the Configuration from Controller or view to get OpenId connect url endpoints?

This is for ASP.Net MVC 5 application. For now i think one way is retrieve .well-known/openid-configuration directly using Authority Url, and set manually Configuration property.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and couldn't find a way to read the configuration in a controller.

I only wanted to get the token endpoint URL without an extra request to the metadata endpoint because the OIDC middleware had already done that job!

Finally I used an extension method from the [IdentityModel](https://www.nuget.org/packages/IdentityModel/) library to get the metadata (sadly with an extra metadata request):

```
var disco = await new HttpClient().GetDiscoveryDocumentAsync("http://localhost:8080/realms/mytenant");
```